# Excel Macro for invoices

Tags: vba, excel

So there is this vendor that sends me spreadsheets every week for their invoices. In the name colum if it equals "BCR Plaza" i would want excel to automatically add another row below that, copy some of the data from the previous row and divide the total in the original row by 2. I already have a macro for all of this. What i cant figure out is how to tell excel that after all of the above actions are executed to go back to the original total and divide that by too as well and replace it with the result.

this is the macro that i currently have now :

```
Sub BlankLine()

Dim Rng As Range
Dim WorkRng As Range
Dim Name As String
Dim Memo As String
Dim dn As Variant
Dim dt As Variant
Dim Total As Variant

On Error Resume Next
xTitleId = "Add New Row"
Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
Set WorkRng = Cells.Select
Set WorkRng = WorkRng.Columns(1)
xLastRow = WorkRng.Rows.Count
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For xRowIndex = xLastRow To 1 Step -1
    Set Rng = WorkRng.Range("A" & xRowIndex)
    If Rng.Value = "BCR Plaza" Then
            dt = Range("B" & xRowIndex).Value
            dn = Range("D" & xRowIndex).Value + 0.5
            Memo = Range("C" & xRowIndex).Value
            Total = (Range("I" & xRowIndex).Value) / 2
        Rng.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
            Range("A" & xRowIndex + 1) = "Billing"
            Range("D" & xRowIndex + 1) = dn
            Range("B" & xRowIndex + 1) = dt
            Range("C" & xRowIndex + 1) = Memo
            Range("I" & xRowIndex + 1) = Total

    End If
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Original File 
[image]

After Macro
[image]

Comment: `On Error Resume Next`? Why? That makes code almost impossible to debug (if used the way that you are using it -- with no checking of `Err.Number` and no matching `On Error GoTo 0`). It is almost always a bad idea to use it that way.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind for next time when i coda vba. Thanks for pointing that out. I just started vba 2 weeks ago so i have a long way to go. Thanks again.

Comment: Nice looking code for just a couple of weeks. Another, somewhat similar remark, get into the habit of using `Option Explicit` (in fact, make it automatic by enabling `Require Variable Declaration` in the VBA editor options). Both of those suggestions will in the long run save you a lot of debugging time.

Comment: Thank you I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try...

```
Sub BlankLine()
Dim Memo As String
Dim dn As Variant
Dim dt As Variant
Dim Total As Variant
Dim xRowIndex As Long, xLastRow As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
xLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For xRowIndex = xLastRow To 2 Step -1
    If Cells(xRowIndex, 1) = "BCR Plaza" Then
        dt = Range("B" & xRowIndex).Value
        dn = Range("D" & xRowIndex).Value + 0.5
        Memo = Range("C" & xRowIndex).Value
        Total = (Range("I" & xRowIndex).Value) / 2
        Rows(xRowIndex + 1).Insert
        Range("A" & xRowIndex + 1) = "Billing"
        Range("D" & xRowIndex + 1) = dn
        Range("B" & xRowIndex + 1) = dt
        Range("C" & xRowIndex + 1) = Memo
        Range("I" & xRowIndex + 1) = Total
        Range("I" & xRowIndex) = Total
    End If
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: It works. It did the same thing as my macro. The problem is that the new row has the total of the original row / 2 but the original row still has the total unchanged. That needs to change and be replaced with the new number which is the other half remaining. All i am trying to do here is split the total of the original in half, shift one half of it to the new row and replace the original total with the remaining half. I am not sure how to do this.....

Comment: You just need to add a line Range("I" & xRowIndex) = Total. See the edited solution.

Comment: Thank you sir. This is amazing!

Comment: @OneaboveAll You're welcome. Glad it worked as desired. :)